# Grails Domain Object inside Command Object always saves

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Command Object that looks as follows...

```
@Validateable
class ACommand implements Serializable
{
  ADomainObject bundleDef
}
```

I use a form to fill the Command then use a controller similar to this

```
def save(ACommand command)
```

I also added the following to my Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.autoFlush = false
```

The problem is even when I don't flush (or even call .save()) it still save to the DB upon return. Has anyone experienced this? Is there a way around it?

**Update**

Also tried the following

```
def save(ACommand command)
{
    try{
       service.saveADomainObject(command.adomain) //save called in here if no error
    }   
    catch(Exception e3){
        log.error(e3);
        command.adomain.discard()
    }
    // renders ...
}
```

This also does not work, even though the discard is called (I set a breakpoint) it still saves.

**Update 2**

I changed my service to look as follows

```
 adomain.discard()
 throw new InvalidObjectException("Blah Blah Blah")
```

It seems to save to the DB directly after the error is thrown. I also confirmed my service is transactional.

**Update 3**

Adding my service classes for reference

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
def saveADomainObject(def adomain, def test) throws InvalidParameterException, InvalidObjectException, Exception{
    if (!test)
    {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("*")
    }
    else
    {
        if (adomain?.id)
        {
            if (!isValidBundleName(adomain, test))
            {
                //TODO: Make default.cannot.save.message
                throw new InvalidObjectException("*")
            }
            errors = updateDomain(adomain)
        }
        else
        {
            errors = createNewdomain(adomain)
        }

        if (errors)
        {
            throw new Exception(errors)
        }
    }
}
protected def updateDomain(def adomain)
{
    adomain.updatedBy = user
    String errors=null;
    if (adomain.getErrors().allErrors.size() > 0)
    {
        errors = adomain.getErrors().allErrors.join("\n")
    }
    return errors
}
private def createNewdomain(def adomain)
{
    adomain.createdBy = user
    String errors = null
    if (adomain.getErrors().allErrors.size() > 0)
    {
        errors = adomain.getErrors().allErrors.join("\n")
    }
    return errors
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it working...

First in the service I added the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` annotations based on this [qoute](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html)

> This version defaults to all methods being read-write transactional (due to the class-level annotation), but the listBooks method overrides this to use a read-only transaction:

That helped but now it wouldn't save period. So I tooke the .save() call out making my controller look like this...

```
def save(ACommand command)
{
  try{
   service.saveADomainObject(command.adomain) //save called in here if no error
   command.adomain(flush:true)
  }   
  catch(Exception e3){
    log.error(e3);
  }
  // renders ...
}
```

I needed the flush:true despite readding the autoFlush so I am not sure there.

Answer (score 1):

If `ADomainObject bundleDef` is bound to an object that is already persistent (i.e. if binding this object loads a record from the database), then changes to this object will automatically be saved to the DB when the Hibernate session is closed.

Assuming you don't want to save the object if the constraints are invalid do this:

```
def save(ACommand command) {

    if (!command.adomain.save()) {
        log.error "Failed to save domain due to errors $command.adomin.errors"
        // other error handling - maybe show a form that allows the user to correct the errors
    } else {
        // object saved successfully, redirect to homepage, throw a party, or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it isn't working I can update my code if that helps

Comment: if you show the body of the controller action that should help

Comment: added the requested info let me know if you need more

Comment: Nope adding it right before the exception throw didn't help either :-(

Comment: Nope yourself, I said you should call it before the service method - see my latest update

Comment: Huh how am I going to do that? What happens if I want to save it in the service? I am confused can you expand

Comment: I wouldn't expect removing transactional to change anything

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to save the domain object only if there are no errors right? If so, see my latest update

Comment: Gave you a +1 because you sent me down the right path but check out my answer for how I got it working.

Comment: I think you've made this a lot more complicated than it needs to be, but it's hard to tell what exactly is happening because I can't see your service method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51272/discussion-between-jackie-and-don)